# What is the best way to compress a sequence of about 2 millions numbers (value range is from 1-->28)

Tags: algorithm, list, integer, lossless-compression

I am trying to compress a list of integer numbers, where:

- There is no negative number.
- The value range of items is from **[1....28]**
- There are totally **2482113** items in the list.
- Currently I'm using **5 bits** to store each number.
- The "appearing" statistic is as below

  - 1 : 1242149
  - 2 : 620038
  - 3 : 309399
  - 4 : 154983
  - 5 : 77816
  - 6 : 38601
  - 7 : 19651
  - 8 : 9790
  - 9 : 4830
  - 10 : 2447
  - 11 : 1253
  - 12 : 597
  - 13 : 303
  - 14 : 130
  - 15 : 73
  - 16 : 23
  - 17 : 17
  - 18 : 4
  - 19 : 4
  - 20 : 2
  - 21 : 1
  - 23 : 1
  - 28 : 1

So please show me the best way to compress this kind of data (estimate compression ratio - if possible - is highly appreciated).

Comment: "What is the best ratio" - how are we supposed to know that?

Comment: If the list is set in stone, you can technically get away with 0 bits: There's no information to transmit, it's always the list you've just posted. </s>

Comment: @delnan, you can't get away with zero bits. At a bare minimum, you need the information in the list posted. In any case, that list gives only the distribution, not the order which would probably be important as well :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Good point about distribution vs. order but assuming the full list is constant and known, you *can* get away with zero bits: Hardcode the list into the decryption program, then you don't need to give it any input to have it produce the list ;-)

Comment: @delnan, well, technically, the program itself then becomes the bitcount but, since I saw the smiley, I won't argue the point :-)

Comment: If the integers are not independently distributed (that is, if their probability distribution of any given number depends on the others) you may be able to get better compression than coding purely from their distribution statistics... e.g., by using some numbers to predict others.

Comment: @comingstorm : I do think that they are independently distributed or I just have not figure out about their relationship yet, but could you please tell me more about this "predict" method? Thank you !

Comment: For example, if you are compressing English text, you can predict each character based on the preceding characters, much better than if you could if you assumed that they were independently distributed and only used the overall single-letter occurrence statistics from the file.  Most general-purpose compression algorithms do this in some form or another, by the way.

Comment: for random data is Huffman coding the way (it is the only compression on which you can estimate the ratio from data you provided). if your data has repetitive patterns then look into LZW (Lempel-Ziv-Welch) compression and if it has many occurrence of the same elements in a row(like 1,1,2,3,3,3,3,2,1,1,1,) then RLE (Run Length Encoding) is also a good idea. but for all of these the compress ratio strongly depends on the data composition and randomness ...

Answer (score 6):

With that sort of distribution <sup>(a)</sup>, you'd probably want to look into a variable-length encoding scheme such as Huffman. That will give you far better compression than the fixed 5-bit size. They work by using less bits to indicate more common values (and more bits to represent uncommon values) to drive down the average bit width.

Just taking a simple case, let's say a `0` bit represents the number one and all the other numbers are represented by a `1` bit followed by your current 5-bit scheme.

That means you save four bits for each value of one (1,242,149 x 4 = 4,968,596 bits) and "waste" one bit for all the other values (1,239,964 bits), a net saving of 3.7 million bits.

That's a "hardcoded" Huffman scheme for your particular data set meant as an illustration of how it works, you'd probably want to be a little more adaptive for arbitrary data sets.

And expanding it to include more of the larger quantities makes an added improvement. We already know the savings for the top value:

```
Bit pattern  Value   Quantity  Saved bits
0                1  1,242,149   4,968,596  (4 per)
1xxxxx          >1  1,239,964   1,239,964- (1 per)
                                ---------
Net saving                      3,728,632  (extra return 3,728,632)
```

For the top two values:

```
Bit pattern  Value   Quantity  Saved bits
0                1  1,242,149   4,968,596  (4 per)
10               2    620,038   1,860,114  (3 per)
11xxxxx         >2    619,926   1,239,852- (2 per)
                                ---------
Net saving                      5,588,858  (extra return 1,860,226)
```

And for the top three:

```
Bit pattern  Value   Quantity  Saved bits
0                1  1,242,149   4,968,596  (4 per)
10               2    620,038   1,860,114  (3 per)
110              3    309,399     618,798  (2 per)
111xxxxx        >3    310,527     931,581- (3 per)
                                ---------
Net saving                      6,515,927  (extra return 927,069)
```

And for the top four:

```
Bit pattern  Value   Quantity  Saved bits
0                1  1,242,149   4,968,596  (4 per)
10               2    620,038   1,860,114  (3 per)
110              3    309,399     618,798  (2 per)
1110             4    154,983     154,983  (1 per)
1111xxxxx       >4    155,544     622,176- (4 per)
                                ---------
Net saving                      6,980,315  (extra return 464,388)
```

At this level, your scheme of having a fixed five bits per number results in 12,410,565 bits. With a net saving of 6,980,315 bits, total compressed size is now 5,430,250 bits, a savings of about 56 over the fixed-bit-size method.

You can see the extra return on investment diminishing pretty quickly as more values are added. Beyond the top four values, you don't save anything with this hardcoded scheme since the bit savings per item go to zero (and negative after that). A truly adaptive encoding would give you more savings (since it's also optimising the `xxxxx` bit) but probably not much.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> A very much contrived distribution by the looks of it. Each quantity is about half the previous quantity, making the variable length encoding an ideal solution.

Comment: Kudos for noting the contrived distribution!

Comment: @paxdiablo: Thank you very much for such an detailed answer. Currently Im busy at work, so when I have time, I will study Huffman coding and post back the result here.

Comment: @comingstorm: Sorry for that "contrived" looking. But I am not intend to made it looks like that. It was my calculated result from a meaning data source.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [Huffman Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding). I don't know the exact details off the top of my head, but the basic principle is to assign less bits to more common numbers and more bits to less common numbers, as needed, so that overall, the average bits per number is less than what you'd expect for a uniform distribution (~5 bits per character)

Comment: +1 for providing more information regarding the algorithm than just a link to the wikipage

Answer (score 2):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding
for information on compressing your information.

Because most of the items in your list have frequency greater the sum of the frequency of all lesser frequency items in your list you will actually get an efficiency of about 2 bits per item.

The exact compression provides an average of 2.00915 bits per symbol. The calculation below reveals my choice of encoding.

(1242149 + 2 * 620038 + 3 * 309399 + 4 * 154983 + 5 * 77816 + 6 * 38601 + 7 * 19651 + 8 * 9790 + 9 * 4830 + 10 * 2447 + 11 * 1253 + 12 * 597 + 13 * 303 + 14 * 130 + 15 * 73 + 16 * 23 + 17 * 17 * 18 * 4 + 19 * 4 * 20 * 2 + 21 * 1 + 22 * (1+1)) / 2482113.0

Note that since your frequencies are not always near inverse powers of 2 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding might get slightly better compression.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Currently Im busy at work, so when I have time, I will check it and post back the result here.